# How can I run WebAssembly in nodejs 14.15

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I download nodejs 14.15.0 from its [official site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and I run the following

```
# ./bin/node --expose-wasm  
Welcome to Node.js v14.15.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> Wasm
Uncaught ReferenceError: Wasm is not defined
```

I think maybe `Wasm` is not avaliable, so I need to use `WebAssembly`.

So I run the following code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const buf = fs.readFileSync('./addTwo.wasm');

function toUint8Array(buf) {
  var u = new Uint8Array(buf.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
    u[i] = buf[i];
  }
  return u;
}

const lib = WebAssembly.instantiateModule(toUint8Array(buf)).exports;
```

However it outputs

```
TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiateModule is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

`WebAssembly.instantiateModule` is not a function on the `WebAssembly` object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly#

Comment: OK, so I should not use `WebAssembly`. However, why `Wasm` is not defined?